# Alternative to SQL Sub Query for Returning Prior Matching Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

SQL Azure Database V12 (SQL Server 2016)

Given the following basic table structure:

```
MyTable
==============
Id int PK
TheDate datetime2 not null
TheValue varchar(50) not null
-- other fields
```

And the following SQL:

```sql
select 
    (   select count(*) 
        from MyTable mt2 
        where 
            mt2.TheValue = mt1.TheValue
            and mt2.TheDate < mt1.TheDate
    ) as PriorCount
    , mt1.TheDate, mt1.TheValue 
from MyTable mt1
where mt1.TheDate between '2016-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
order by mt1.TheDate desc
```

Example Output:

```sql
PriorCount   TheDate                 TheValue
===============================================
   1         2016-06-01 00:00:00     Foo
   2         2016-05-01 00:00:00     Bar
   1         2016-04-01 00:00:00     Bar
   0         2016-03-01 00:00:00     Foo
   0         2016-02-01 00:00:00     Bar
```

I've reviewed the [OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), but couldn't come up with anything to return the prior counts. Is there an alternative SQL query to return the `PriorCount` without a sub select?

Comment: You could also just `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY` the count of everything before the given date with that given value, which technically isn't a sub select.

Comment: @ZLK, could you provide an example? Maybe an alternative answer?

Comment: You could write your subquery as an apply, like `SELECT Z.PriorCount, mt1.TheDate, mt2.TheValue FROM MyTable mt1 CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE TheValue = mt1.TheValue AND TheDate < mt1.TheDate) Z(PriorCount) WHERE...`

Comment: @ZLK - the cross apply works as well; maybe consider adding it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select count(*) over (partition by TheValue order by TheDate) - 1 as PriorCount,
       mt1.TheDate, mt1.TheValue 
from MyTable mt1
where mt1.TheDate between '2016-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
order by mt1.TheDate desc
```

**Edit:**

If you want to apply `COUNT` to the whole table, then you can use the following query:

```
select PriorCount, TheDate, TheValue
from (
   select count(*) over (partition by TheValue 
                         order by TheDate) - 1 as PriorCount,
          TheDate, TheValue 
   from MyTable 
   order by TheDate desc) as t
where t.TheDate between '2016-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
```

Comment: This almost works. However, the `PriorCount` should include all dates, not just the date range in the where clause. I think the over clause is only including the current result set?

Comment: @MetroSmurf The `OVER` clause is applied on the records returned by the query *after* `WHERE` executes. You can just use the `OVER` in a subquery and apply the `WHERE` in an outer query. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: The edit indeed works with a minor tweak, re: `order by TheDate desc) as t` needs to remove the order by, otherwise a SQL error occurs: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.` I also noticed the new query is substantially slower, but I'll play with the indexes and see what I can come up with. Thanks!